Datagridview add correct number of lines but no data in the cells
I have to extract data from my api to put it in a datagridview on my .net application but the content of the cells is empty even though the json data is correct
I tried to put msgbox at differents steps of the program to see if the data i received from my api was correct and everything seems fine and i can't find where the problem is located.
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        DataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill

        Dim margin As New Padding(100, 500, 100, 250)
        Me.Margin = margin

        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
        InitialiserColonnesDataGridView()
        RefreshData()
        AdjustButtonPosition()
    End Sub

    Private Sub InitialiserColonnesDataGridView()

        DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()


        Dim deleteButtonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
        deleteButtonColumn.HeaderText = "Supprimer"
        deleteButtonColumn.Name = "DeleteButtonColumn"
        deleteButtonColumn.Text = "Supprimer"
        deleteButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
        deleteButtonColumn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, deleteButtonColumn)


        Dim editButtonColumn As New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
        editButtonColumn.HeaderText = "Modifier"
        editButtonColumn.Name = "EditButtonColumn"
        editButtonColumn.Text = "Modifier"
        editButtonColumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
        editButtonColumn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
        DataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, editButtonColumn)


        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("id", "ID")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("nom", "Nom")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("prix", "Prix")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("description", "Description")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("annee", "Année")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("quantite_stock", "Quantité en stock")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("reference", "Référence")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("fournisseur", "Fournisseur")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("info", "Info")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("maison", "Maison")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("famille", "Famille")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("region", "Région")
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add("image", "Image")

    End Sub

    Private Sub AdjustButtonPosition()
        Dim bottomMargin As Integer = 10
        Dim buttonLocation As New Point(Me.ClientSize.Width - Button1.Width - 10, Me.ClientSize.Height - Button1.Height - bottomMargin)
        Button1.Location = buttonLocation
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Dim ajoutVinForm As New AjoutVin()
        ajoutVinForm.ShowDialog()
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        AdjustButtonPosition()
        RefreshData()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub RefreshData()
        Dim apiUrl As String = Config.BaseApiUrl & "/produit"

        Using client As New HttpClient()
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(apiUrl)
            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                Dim jsonString As String = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                Dim produits As List(Of Produit) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Produit))(jsonString)
                DataGridView1.DataSource = produits
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Une erreur est survenue lors du chargement des données depuis l'API.")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            If e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns("DeleteButtonColumn").Index Then
                Dim confirmationResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer cet enregistrement ?", "Confirmation de suppression", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                If confirmationResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    Dim idToDelete As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("id").Value)
                    DeleteRecord(idToDelete)
                End If
            ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = DataGridView1.Columns("EditButtonColumn").Index Then
                Dim confirmationResult As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Voulez-vous vraiment modifier cet enregistrement ?", "Confirmation de modification", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
                If confirmationResult = DialogResult.Yes Then
                    Dim idToEdit As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("id").Value)
                    OpenModifierProduitForm(idToEdit)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenModifierProduitForm(id As Integer)
        Me.Hide()
        Dim modifierProduitForm As New modifierProduit(id)
        modifierProduitForm.ShowDialog()
        Me.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Async Sub DeleteRecord(id As Integer)
        Dim apiUrl As String = Config.BaseApiUrl & $"/produit/{id}"

        Using client As New HttpClient()
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.DeleteAsync(apiUrl)

            If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
                RefreshData()
                MessageBox.Show("Ligne supprimée avec succès.")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Erreur lors de la suppression de la ligne.")
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Commandes_Form.Show()
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Produit
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property nom As String
    Public Property prix As Decimal
    Public Property description As String
    Public Property annee As Integer
    Public Property quantite_stock As Integer
    Public Property reference As String
    Public Property fournisseur As String
    Public Property info As String
    Public Property maison As String
    Public Property famille As String
    Public Property region As String
    Public Property image As String
End Class


Why is this question tagged ASP.NET when it's obviously a WinForms application? It's important that you put some thought into the tags and apply as many relevant ones as you can and no irrelevant ones.

Why are you setting things like WindowState, Dock and Margin in the Load event handler? Those properties should be set in the designer.

You don't debug code using MsgBox. You use the debugger. If you don't know how to debug, stop what you're doing and learn that first. You set breakpoints at appropriate places in the code and then step through the sections on interest, examining the state of variables, etc, using the Autos, Locals, Watch and Immediate windows.

What is the value of produits.Count? If it is 0 then you have a problem with the deserialization.

@jmcilhinney it's a stackoverflow admin that told me to put asp.net as well i just went with what he said since i'm a beginner and yes I can try debugging with breakpoints as well but i don't think i will be able to find where are my errors thanks for the advices tho

I can only assume that someone thought it was a GridView rather than a DataGridView if they recommended the ASP.NET tag.

I would suggest that you should be adding the columns to your grid in the designer too, rather than in code. There's really no point writing code to do anything you can do in the designer when you know what to do at design time. Code is for things that you won't know until run time.

@jmcilhinney I would just set .AutogenerateColumns = True, bind the data with List(Of Produits) as he does in the code (DataGridView1.DataSource = produits ), and then insert the button columns. I find setting the columns of a DGV in the designer overhead when you need to add/remove columns.

@HardCode, you're probably right that the data columns should probably be autogenerated, now that I look more closely, although I'd still add the button columns in the designer.

@jmcilhinney I've never added columns in the designer and then also autogenerated columns to a bindable data source. I'll have to try that.

@HardCode, in this case, the button columns come first, so it's very easy to add them first in the designer and to have the rest autogenerated afterwards. If you wanted the designer columns elsewhere, you could set their DisplayIndex after setting the DataSource. See here for my example of adding a combo box column in the designer and autogenerating the rest, then moving the designed column.

Thank you everyone it's working ! I will now start using designer as well didn't know not using it could be a source of errors.

The problem is that you are not setting the DataPropertyName of your grid columns. If AutoGenerateColumns is True then setting the DataSource will create a column for each column/property in the items and bind them. If you add the columns to the grid yourself, it's your responsibility to tell them which property/column of the data source to bind to. You do that by setting the DataPropertyName. As I said in the comments, you should be adding the grid columns in the designer and setting the DataPropertyName there too.
Having looked at your code more closely, I think that I would add the two button columns in the designer, then just set the DataSource and let the rest of the columns be generated automatically. That will also set the DataPropertyName automatically and your data will display as intended
